Calculate weight for GLM-quasi poisson model
I am running several models with the quasi-Poisson family. I am looking at data from vulture restaurants. Vulture count was modelled at each site as a function of either a linear or quadratic effect of date or month, and fixed effects of site, season and interactions among them. Models were fitted with quasi-Poisson errors using a log-link function in R. The best models were selected by the lowest quasi-AICc score. To calculate QAICc scores, I re-ran all models with standard Poisson errors, and corrected AICc scores using the dispersion from the most complex model in each set (date2 × site × season) using the R-package “bblme” (Bolker 2016).
I would like to demonstrate the level of support for the top models by reporting QAICc weight. But I couldn't find online how to do it. Is there a function from a package I could use to calculate the weight for each model?
Here are the results I got from the package "bblme", named as Table_DeltaQAICc:

I tried calculating the weight by following this equation I saw online for an example with IC. Model weights are computed simply according to: e(−δIC/2)
Table_DeltaQAICc$Weight <- exp((-Table_DeltaQAICc$dqAICc)/2)

Here the results I got, is it appropriate how I calculate the weight for each model?


Are you looking for model-averaging type weights, as with Burnham and Anderson type multimodel inference?

Thanks, I actually find my answer, I was not using the proper formula, I used the following code and it is not working.
Table_DeltaQAICc$Weight <- exp(-0.5*Table_DeltaQAICc$dqAICc)/ sum(exp(-0.5*Table_DeltaQAICc$dqAICc))
